# Rust Vec reverse_exact: capacity will be greater than or equal to self.len() + additional

Tags: rust

In the Rust document Vec, the method `reserve_exact` said about:

```
After calling reserve_exact, capacity will be greater than or equal to self.len() + additional
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve_exact

But when I read the code from https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#408

I see the new capacity is equal always `size + additonal`. So I'm not sure which part of the reserve_exact() will make capacity is `greater than` `self.len() + additional`

```
    fn grow_exact(&mut self, len: usize, additional: usize) -> Result<(), TryReserveError> {
        if mem::size_of::<T>() == 0 {
            // Since we return a capacity of `usize::MAX` when the type size is
            // 0, getting to here necessarily means the `RawVec` is overfull.
            return Err(CapacityOverflow.into());
        }

        let cap = len.checked_add(additional).ok_or(CapacityOverflow)?;
        let new_layout = Layout::array::<T>(cap);

        // `finish_grow` is non-generic over `T`.
        let ptr = finish_grow(new_layout, self.current_memory(), &mut self.alloc)?;
        self.set_ptr_and_cap(ptr, cap);
        Ok(())
    }
```

Maybe I miss part of the code, thanks if you can point what I missed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    println!("vec1 len: {}, cap: {}", vec1.len(), vec1.capacity());
    vec1.reserve_exact(3);
    println!("vec1 len: {}, cap: {}", vec1.len(), vec1.capacity());
    println!("   expected: cap >= 8\n");

    let mut vec2 = Vec::with_capacity(100);
    vec2.push(1);
    vec2.push(2);
    vec2.push(3);
    println!("vec2 len: {}, cap: {}", vec2.len(), vec2.capacity());
    vec2.reserve_exact(3);
    println!("vec2 len: {}, cap: {}", vec2.len(), vec2.capacity());
    println!("   expected: cap >= 6");
}
```

```
vec1 len: 5, cap: 5
vec1 len: 5, cap: 8
   expected >= 8

vec2 len: 3, cap: 100
vec2 len: 3, cap: 100
   expected >= 6
```

Q.E.D.

---

The line that warrants the `greater than` [is here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#338):

```rust
if self.needs_to_grow(len, additional) ...
```

As in the example, if your capacity is `100`, but your content is only `3`, and you want to grow it by an additional `3`, nothing happens, because it's already big enough, fulfilling the `bigger or equal` requirement. And as `100` is obviously bigger than `6`, this should hopefully answer your question ;)

Comment: Make sense, I was too focused to grow more than the additional argument but I forget the case does nothing when capacity is greater than the current len + additional.

Thanks for your answer!